# android SQLiteException: no such column on custom roms

Tags: android, android-sqlite, xiaomi

On devices with modified android versions i get this error. For example on Xiaomi devices.

```
String query = "select * from dialogues where userId = ? and topChat = 0 order by updatedAtByClient desc";
Cursor dialogRes = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{userId});
```

Here i get exception:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: topChat (code 1):,
while compiling: select * from dialogues where userId = ? and topChat = 0 
order by updatedAtByClient desc
```

I have written the exception message by hand, because the user has sent me it in a screenshot, so there might be typos.

How can this be fixed, and why does this happen?

UPD1:
the create table statement looks similar to this:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dialogues(fieldName VARCHAR, camelCaseFieldName VARCHAR,
topChat INTEGER, createdAt DATE);";
```

And i have a correctly implemented update method for when im changing the DB structure, but this particular table and field name did not change for a long time.

UPD2:
i have made an apk for the user with problems, that logs that table columns, and i did see the problematic column in the log, and user says that this version works ok.

So seems that this error does not happen 100% of times. Very strange. Maybe there is a way to check the database for integrity after creating it, and recreate tables with errors?

Comment: Can you show us the `CREATE TABLE` statement? Also may be worth giviing that user a version which can [list the columns of the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550896/return-all-columns-of-a-sqlite-table-in-android) so you can see how the table is being created on the device.

Comment: Because if this is happening only on certain devices and works "fine" on stock Android, then you may need to do your debugging on that particular device. See if you have any Device Labs near where you live.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this would be a `xiaomi` issue. it rather seems be the result of an unfortunate migration, where a new column had not been added and subsequently, the user might still work with the previous version of the table. and there is no other logical explanation for an absent column), simply because either the `CREATE TABLE` statement works - or it doesn't.

one can still work around it with `ALTER TABLE`. eg. when that `SQLiteException` occurs, `addColumnIfNotExists("dialogues", "topChat", "INTEGER DEFAULT 0");` ...in order not to cause data-loss by dropping the table, only because it lacks some column.

```
public void addColumnIfNotExists(String tableName, String columnName, String dataType) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName, null);
        if(! Arrays.asList(cursor.getColumnNames()).contains(columnName)) {
            db.execSQL(String.format("ALTER TABLE %s ADD COLUMN %s %s", tableName, columnName, dataType));
        }
    } finally {
        if(cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have written that this is not a migration issue. My database is updating correctly when needed, and this table and column were not changed for a long time before this error.

Comment: @lxknvlk still sounds unlikely, that `CREATE TABLE` would have succeeded alike that and there is nothing fancy about the query, where a driver version would make a difference - except that it does not provide a `DEFAULT` value for that column... the method provided should fix the issue, no matter the cause.